# Get option selected image for conformation email attached

Tags: magento2, order-email, color-swatches

I like to get selected option image of swatch option, for design email template. Now i'm getting a parent image instred of selected image. 
Eg:
  in my website parent image is black color, i choose swatch option in red colour.
In order conformation email template parent image ie., black colour image was displaying. i like to get selected (red colour) image.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Go to Admin sidebar tap Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout ->
Expand Shopping cart  section ->  Set Grouped Product Image and Configurable Product Image to -> Product Thumbnail Itself

Comment: Hi @Bilal , I set as it like in admin pannel, but still i'm getting parent image in my email template.

Comment: have you cleared the cache?

Comment: Yes, i cleared my all cache